# What is the location of a "in.txt" QFile while developing in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am using this code to read some values from a plain text file.

However the problem is the defaults does not get read. I looked at this with the debugger and it says that the exist property for my file object is false after the QFile file("defaults.txt"); line.

I tried putting this file in multiple locations but Qt fails to detect it.

Where should this file go while developing?

I tried:

C:\coding\build-coords-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\defaults.txt

```
void MainWindow::readDefaults() {
    QFile file("defaults.txt");
       if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
           return;

       int count = 0;
       QTextStream in(&file);
       while (!in.atEnd()) {
           QString line = in.readLine();
           switch (count)
           {
           case 0:
               deltaX->setValue(line.toDouble());
               break;
           case 1:
               deltaY->setValue(line.toDouble());
               break;
           case 2:
               deltaZ->setValue(line.toDouble());
               break;
           }
           count++;
       }
}
```

Comment: In my experience it should be in `build-coords-Desktop...Mingw_32bit-Debug` that's where executable file is located after build. However, this is only true if your selected build is Debug not Release or a custom one

Comment: It's quite simple: you shouldn't be assuming anything about the working directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If specified path is not absolute, it is considered relative to the process' *working directory*. It's not Qt-specific. All native file-related functions on common OSs work in the same way.

Generally, working directory can be anything. It depends on the way you run the process. For example, if you run it from the shell, it is by default the same as the shell's working directory. It may not be the same as the directory containing executable file or project sources.

You can view default working directory used by Qt Creator. Select "Projects" icon at the left panel, switch to "Run" tab to view Run settings. It will contain "Working directory" field. You can set any working directory. It's by default the same as the build directory.

[image]

A common tactic to specify input file is to read it from application arguments. Use `QCoreApplication::arguments()` to get arguments list (discard first argument as it's the exe file name) and specify file path in "Arguments" field of the project's Run settings in Qt Creator. It's OK to specify full path here, so you shouldn't worry about working directory.

Comment: Thanks very much. Mine was set to: C:\coding\build-coords-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\ after placing the file there it works.

Answer (score 0):

i encountered a similar problem. it was caused that the applications working directory is the `build directory` not the `project directory`.

try to place the file where the executable is and it should work.